# Comparing 2 substrings in C

Tags: c, linux

I having trouble reading a string of characters from a file and then comparing them for the first part of my homework on ubuntu using C.
So the program compiles fine but it seems I get stuck in an infinite loop when it gets to the while loop under the compare string portion of the code. Thanks.

Also, can I get some advice on how to take multiple inputs from the terminal to compare the string from the 'bar' file and the string of x substring of characters after that in the terminal. My output should look like:

```
% echo "aaab" > bar
% ./p05 bar aa B
2
1
%
```

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void /*int argc, char *argv[]*/) 
{

  /******* Open, Read, Close file**********/
  FILE *ReadFile;

  ReadFile = fopen(/*argv[1]*/"bar", "r");

  if(NULL == ReadFile)
    {
      printf("\n file did not open \n");
      return 1;
    }

  fseek(ReadFile, 0 , SEEK_END);  
  int size = ftell(ReadFile); 
  rewind(ReadFile);                

  char *content = calloc( size +1, 1); 

  fread(content,1,size,ReadFile);     

  /*fclose(ReadFile); */                 

  printf("you made it past opening and reading file\n");
  printf("your file size is %i\n",size);

  /*********************************/


  /******String compare and print*****/
  int count =0;
  const char *tmp = "Helololll";
  while (content = strstr(content,"a"))
    {
      count++;
      tmp++;
  }
  printf("Your count is:%i\n",count);

  /***********************************/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/

Comment: remove the `tmp++;` from the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following loop is infinite if the character `'a'` occurs in `content`.

```
while (content = strstr(content, "a"))
{
    count ++;
    tmp ++;
}
```

It resets `content` to point to the location of the first occurrence of `'a'` on the first iteration.  Future iterations will not change the value of `content`.  IOW, `content` points to `"aaab"` so the call to `strstr` will find the first `'a'` every time.  If you replace `tmp++` with `content++` inside of your loop, then it will be closer to what you want.  I would probably write this with a `for` loop to make it a little more clear that you are iterating.

```
char const * const needle = "a";
for (char *haystack=content; haystack=strstr(haystack, needle); haystack++) {
    count++;
}
```

The *haystack* is incremented so that it always decreases in size.  Eventually, you will not find the *needle* in the *haystack* and the loop will terminate.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was driving me crazy. Any advice on how to put in multiple augments into the int main function so it can check how many occurrence each substring have in common with the 'bar' file

Comment: You actually have the argument stuff commented out.  `int argc` is the "argument count" and `char *argv[]` is the "argument vector".  When you run your program as `./p05 bar aa B`, `argc` will equal 4 and `argv` will contain the strings `"./p05"`, `"bar"`, `"aa"`, and `"B"`.  Note that the first argument, `argv[0]`, is the name of the program `"./p05"` in this case.